# how to assign a numeric shortcut to a button o c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to assign a number key for a calculator project, how ever, it only accepts letters as shortcut.
Using a letter:

```
private void Calculator_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
   if(e.KeyCode.ToString() == "A"){
      MessaBox.Show("hi");
   }
}
```

And it works fine, but what I really want to do is to replace "A" for "1", and when I do it doesn't work.
I also already tried this:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D1 || e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
      MessaBox.Show("hi");
   }
}
```

Also if this KeyDown event is a handler for your Form I assume you've set your form's KeyPreview property to true, so your can intercept the event first on a form level.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I just try ur code its work fine with me but you need to enable KeyPreview property of the form to True ;

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("HI");
            }
```

Comment: for some reason Keys.NumPad1 does not work here. I had to use Keys.D1.